# No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'ProjectName'

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am attempting to update my database and Add-Migration. I am getting the following errors:

PM> Add-Migration update

No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Infrastructure'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

PM>Enable-Migrations

No context type was found in the assembly 'Infrastructure'.

DbContext is located inside Infrastructure.
I have five previous Migrations that have been completed without error. I have not changed my DbContext method in between the last migration and the one I am attempting now.

Infrastructure.Data:

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class MovieshopDBContext : DbContext
    {
        //will generate the DB tables
        public MovieshopDBContext(DbContextOptions<MovieshopDBContext> options) :base(options)
        {
            //specify options

            
        }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Trailer> Trailers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cast> Casts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Crew> Crews { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MovieCast> MovieCasts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MovieCrew> MovieCrews { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I have what I believe are all of the necessary dependencies and NuGet packages installed.
Things I have tried:
Rebuilt, reran commands with -force.
Restarted machine.
Checked [Microsoft.docs.com](https://microsoft.docs.com).

Comment: Where are you registering your DBContext

Comment: Try specifying both the context's project name and the startup project name explicitly ( with `--project` and `--startup-project`). I have had issues with Visual Studio not respecting the 'Current Project' setting in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours and hours of searching, I found the answer:

Credit to: Henryk Budzinski on SO

1. Remove EntityFramework (not EntityFrameworkCore) references from all projects in the solution
2. Open the solution folder in Explorer (Windows Explorer)
3. Close VS
4. delete .vs folder
5. Open the solution again
6. Run update-database and the alert is gone

Worked for me flawlessly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).